# configure ip for bitnami owncloud virtual appliance

Tags: owncloud

I installed Bitnami owncloud virtual appliance stack on Virtual box and within no time, I was able to sync files to and from this box. However, the main problem with Virtual Box is that the IP address keeps changing when the owncloud instance is powered off and then turned back on - which makes sense. Is there any way to keep the server IP static so that we don't need to configure the clients everytime the IP is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the config (from auto to static) in the following way

sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces (“vi” or “nano”)

```
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.0.100 
# your own IP  

netmask 255.255.255.0 
# network mask

gateway 192.168.0.1 
# standard gateway (router)

dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 
# DNS (optional)
```

/etc/init.d/networking restart (restart network)

ifconfig

for the IP addresses check or you “shutdown –h now” (reboot)). Please, keep in mind that multiple copies need multiple IP's. In Virtual Box remember to switch between NAT and Bridge - if required.